# Recording a video of a crime without criminal's knowledge and consent; is it considered evidence in Greece?

Tags: evidence, recording

According to Article 370A of the [Greek penal code](http://www.ministryofjustice.gr/site/kodikes/%CE%95%CF%85%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BF/%CE%A0%CE%9F%CE%99%CE%9D%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%9F%CE%A3%CE%9A%CE%A9%CE%94%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%91%CE%A3/tabid/432/language/el-GR/Default.aspx):

> **Παραβίαση του απορρήτου της τηλεφωνικής επικοινωνίας και της προφορικής συνομιλίας**
>   Όποιος αθέμιτα παρακολουθεί με ειδικά τεχνικά μέσα ή αποτυπώνει σε υλικό φορέα προφορική συνομιλία μεταξύ τρίτων ή αποτυπώνει σε υλικό φορέα μη δημόσια πράξη άλλου, τιμωρείται με κάθειρξη μέχρι δέκα ετών.

Translation by me*:

> **Breach of confidentiality of telephone communication and oral conversation**
>   Anyone who unlawfully monitors with special technical means or stores in a medium an oral conversation of third parties or stores in a medium someone else's non public act, may be imprisoned for up to ten years.

"Imprisonment for up to ten year" in Greek law means that the offender will get a minimum of 5 years in prison, without parole.

---

According to many Greek newspapers and lawyer websites **such recordings can't be used as evidence**. This includes even cases where the unlawfully recorded act is an act of treason, murder or of similar severity.

1. Is the above claim true?
2. If it is true, are there any cases in which this would benefit society?

*<sub>(I'm not a lawyer so feel free to fix terminology issues)</sub>

Comment: Define "non public act". Just because a criminal doesn't want anyone to know about his crime that doesn't make it non public. If you break into my house it's public unless _I_ declare it to be private.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't know the definition of "non public act" under greek law, but i can provide examples of conversations that were _probably_ considered private, where the third party was attempting bribe of a parliament member. [The case was dropped](http://www.tovima.gr/society/article/?aid=661856) because the recorded conversation was obtained in an unlawful manner making it unusable as evidence. The [conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_p7__xrzNg) took place in a hotel.